# How to read/parse Content from OkNegotiatedContentResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In one of my API actions (`PostOrder`) I *may* be consuming another action in the API (`CancelOrder`). Both return a JSON formatted `ResultOrderDTO` type, set as a `ResponseTypeAttribute` for both actions, which looks like this:

```
public class ResultOrderDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PaymentCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> Issues { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is reading/parsing the `ResultOrderDTO` response from `CancelOrder`, so that I can use it as response for `PostOrder`. This is what my `PostOrder` code looks like:

```
// Here I call CancelOrder, another action in the same controller
var cancelResponse = CancelOrder(id, new CancelOrderDTO { Reason = CancelReason.Unpaid });

if (cancelResponse is OkNegotiatedContentResult<ResultOrderDTO>)
{
    // Here I need to read the contents of the ResultOrderDTO
}
else if (cancelResponse is InternalServerErrorResult)
{
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ResultError(ErrorCode.InternalServer)));
}
```

When I use the debugger, I can see that the `ResultOrderDTO` it is there *somewhere* in the response (looks like the `Content`) as shown in the pic below:

[image: Debugger]

but `cancelResponse.Content` does not exist (or at least I don't have access to it before I cast my response to something else) and I have no idea about how to read/parse this `Content`. Any idea?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply cast the response object to `OkNegotiatedContentResult<T>`. The Content property is object of type T. which in your case is object of `ResultOrderDTO`.

```
if (cancelResponse is OkNegotiatedContentResult<ResultOrderDTO>)
{
    // Here's how you can do it. 
    var result = cancelResponse as OkNegotiatedContentResult<ResultOrderDTO>;
    var content = result.Content;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try this. Thanks.